# replacing "VALUE! with a - in a calculating formula

Tags: excel-2010

I have a simple formula =sum(G6-E7) it calculates a remaining budget based on the projected project budget. I want to replace the "#VALUE!" with a dash. How do I add that to my formula?

Comment: More information is needed please. Which cell has the #Value! that you want to replace with a dash?

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your formula with IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(yourFormula,"-")
```